# finding itemIdentifier UUID in an array

Tags: swift, swift4

I have an array of items, like this:

```
[
    [notes: "notes", name: "name", createdAt: date, itemIdentifier: UUID],  
    [notes: "notes2", name: "name2", createdAt: date, itemIdentifier: UUID],
    ...
]
```

I want to find the entry with a given UUID, for instance, `738A31D9-2A5D-46DB-BEAF-0FCA017F4A2F`.

My code for finding a name works:

```
if let item = array.first(where: {$0.name == "name"}) {
    // do something
    print(item)
} else {
    // item could not be found
}
```

But for finding a given UUID it doesn't work.

```
if let item = array.first(where: {$0.itemIdentifier == 738A31D9-2A5D-46DB-BEAF-0FCA017F4A2F}) {
   // do something
   print(item)
} else {
   // item could not be found
}
```

The error that pops up is:

> Expected a digit after integer literal prefix

With a red line under the A in 738A31D9.

What am I doing wrong and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should rewrite `if` like:

```
if let item = array.first(where: { $0.itemIdentifier == UUID(uuidString: "738A31D9-2A5D-46DB-BEAF-0FCA017F4A2F") }) {
   // do something
   print(item)
}
```

because the `738A31D9-2A5D-46DB-BEAF-0FCA017F4A2F` value is `UUID` type.

Comment: then the error is: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UUID' and 'String'. the itemIdentifier is of type UUID and not of type string.

Comment: @arakweker, really sorry, my mistake. i updated the answer.